# how to closed the modal in angular 5

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I have created the dialog for my form. The issue that I am facing is, when click the **SUBMIT** button to submit the form, the dialog is not getting closed. What is wrong with below code? The modal opens, but now how do I close it after submitting the form?

modal.ts

```
openMod(): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FeedbackFormComponent, {
    width: '800px'
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are following the right path of opening the material dialog. Just add a new line to catch the close event.

```
openDialog(type): void {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ComponentName, {
    width: '450px',
  });

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
     console.log(result);
  });
}
```

and in your dialog if you want to close it on button click, follow this example.

```
button_clicked() {
  // You can also send any data from here to the calling component
  this.dialogRef.close(data);
}
```